How to make DataGridTextColumn fill all remaining space
I've read a lot of posts on similar issues but can't figure out how to get rid of the extra space on the right. The middle column (which should be the rightmost column with the "240" and "0" values) has a width of * but when the window is made wider and narrower it doesn't adjust to fill all remaining space. Thanks in advance for your help.

<UserControl x:Class="Foo.PropertiesPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RevitDataValidator"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Background="LightGray"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid
        x:Name="OverallGrid"
        Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <ItemsControl
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PackData}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding PackParameters}">
                            <DataGrid.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextStateParameter}">
                                    <TextBox
                                        Text="{Binding Value}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.Resources>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn
                                    Width="150"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn
                                    Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
</UserControl>


There is no javascript that can be used as a snippet. Your code is XAML and should be highlited as such

The easiest is to configure the DataGrid to distribute the available space evenly amongst all columns. You do this by setting DataGrid.ColumnWidth property to *.
If you only want to make the last column to fill the remaining space, you must set the width of all columns except the last to an explicit value or Auto while DataGrid.ColumnWidth is set to *.
To prevent the columns from shrinking you have to set the DataGridColumn.MinWidth property. This also guarateens that a horizontal scroll bar will appear.
And if you don't want to distribute the available space evenly between all columns you must also set the DataGridCOlumn.Width property.
For example, to make only the last column fill the remaining space you must set DataGrid.ColumnWidth to *, and all columns except the last must have an explicit DataGridColumn.Width (e.g. Auto) and all columns, including the last, must have their DataGridColumn.MinWidth set. If DataGridColumn.Width is set to Auto then the DataGrid will calculate the size based on the bigger width of header and cell.
The key is that when DataGrid.ColumnWidth is set to * or e.g. DataGridLength.SizeToCells then the DataGrid will automatically recalculate the layout if the condition has changed.
Setting the width locally on the DataGridColumn results in a single calculation, the moment the DataGridCell is created.
Available space is distributed evenly amongst all columns:
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" />

Only particular columns will share the available space. In the following example, only the last column will fill the remaining space:
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Non stretching column"
                        Width="Auto"
                        MinWidth="100" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Filling column" 
                        MinWidth="100" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

